# Printing the next word in a sequence

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new FileReader(selectFile.getSelectedFile()));
int count = 0;
System.out.println("SampleName,RecordingTime,PeakName,Amount");
while(input.hasNext() && count <= 1000){
    count++;
    String word = input.next();

    if (count == 2){
        System.out.print(word + ",");
    }
    if (count == 36){
        System.out.print(word + ",");
    }

    if (count == 64){
        System.out.print(word + ",");
    }

    if (count == 68){
        System.out.print(word + ",");
    }

}
```

How can I print the next word in a sequence?
For example, the program reads a text file like the one below.

Hello          there

Name:          John
Amount:           12.0

How would I go to print the word after Name: in this case John or the Amount: 12.0
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is with the 2,36,64 and 68 values for the count ?

Comment: It`s pretty much the same thing as the example. The words I want to print, but since not all files have the same number of words the code I have isn`t doing what I need it to do.

Comment: But is that the count of the index at which that tag is found ?

Comment: Well yes and no. Yes for some files and No for others since the files that the program will be reading have different number of words so the tag position actually changes.

Comment: Provide a sample file. It would help to know the expected content of a file.

Comment: I was going to provide a screen shot, but I can`t I need more than 10 reps. I`m new to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this.

```
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String word = input.next();
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile("Name:");
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("Amount:");            
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(word);
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(word);
        if(matcher1.matches()){
            System.out.println(input.next());
        }
        if(matcher2.matches()){
            System.out.println(input.next());
        }           
    }
```